# How to change version number in json that isn't an integer

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord, discord.js

**I am trying to make it so every time I run the following code it goes into the JSON file and update it.**

**My issue:**
*1.* The JSON file for the version is a string not an integer

**I assume this should fix?**
My idea is that maybe I can get the version, remove all the `.`'s in the string given, convert it into an integer, add `1` to the integer, than convert it back to the string and add the `.`'s again, than use that number to update it in the JSON file.

**CODE:**
*JSON:*

```json
{"version":"0.9.1"}
```

*JavaScript:*

```js
const package = require('../package.json');

const myIntents = new Intents(32767);

const client = new Client({ intents: myIntents });

client.once('ready', () => {
    incrementVersionNumber(package.version, ".");

    console.log(`Successfully logged in as ${client.user.tag} | Version: ${package.version}`);
});
```

**Function:**

```js
function incrementVersionNumber(version, delimiter) {
    const arr = version.split(delimiter);
    
    if (arr[arr.length - 1] == 9) {
        if (arr[arr.length - 2] == 9) {
            arr[arr.length - 3] = (Number(arr[arr.length - 3]) + 1).toString();
            arr[arr.length - 2] = "0";
            arr[arr.length - 1] = "0";
        } else {
            arr[arr.length - 2] = (Number(arr[arr.length - 2]) + 1).toString();
            arr[arr.length - 1] = "0";
        }
    } else if (arr[arr.length - 2] == 9 && arr[arr.length - 1] != 9) {
        arr[arr.length - 1] = (Number(arr[arr.length - 1]) + 1).toString();
    } else {
        arr[arr.length - 1] = (Number(arr[arr.length - 1]) + 1).toString();
    };

    const newVer = `${arr}`.replace(',', '.').replace(',', '.');
    
    const newVersion = `{"version":"${newVer}"}`;

    const newVersionObject = JSON.parse(newVersion);

    const newVersionJSON = JSON.stringify(newVersionObject);

    fs.writeFile("./src/Data/config.json", newVersionJSON, 'utf8', function error(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });

    console.log(`Updated to version ${newVer} from version ${version}`);
}
```

**Note:**
I do have more code in this file, I am just showing the needed parts.

**Update:**
My issue is now that `console` logs that it was a success, but the `JSON` file doesn't actually get updated. I have no clue what is causing this issue.

**Fix:**
I realized the code cant change anything in the `package.json` file so I changed it to user `config.json` in my `Data` folder and it now works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Something like where `ver = "1.1.5"` and `delimiter = "."`

```js
function incrementVersionNumber(ver, delimiter) {
    let arr = ver.split(delimiter);
    let i = arr.length - 1;
    arr[i] = Number(arr[i]) + 1;
    return arr.join(delimiter);
}

console.log(incrementVersionNumber("1.1.4", "."));
```

Comment: How can I make it change the version in the JSON file though?

Comment: Well, what produces the JSON file?

Comment: I don't know what you mean buy that.

Comment: Where does the JSON file come from? Is it just a file sitting there in the program, cloud, local disk, can you even edit it? And you want to update it every time "the client is ready"?

Comment: I want to edit the file everytime the code is run. I can access the file. It is called package.json in my node.js project.

Comment: To access the file from index.js the path is `../package.json`

Comment: I've also noticed how if the version = "1.1.9" instead of going to "1.2.0" it goes to "1.1.10" and so on.

Comment: Update, I got it to add correctly but now I am having trouble actually changing the value in the JSON file with `fs.write`. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: I suggest looking into semantic versioning. As to overwriting your file, first you should read in your file, parse it to a JSON object, update the version, the write the JSON object back into the package.json

Comment: I had done that, but it doesn't work. The code is correct though I believe.